# Cross-domain sitemap submission

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

I am verified owner of 10 different domains in Google Search Console.

I am hosting sitemaps for all 10 websites under one of these 10 domains. Based on the [Official Docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/sitemaps/large-sitemaps#manage-sitemaps-for-multiple-sites), this should not be a problem, because I am a verified owner of all of these properties.

[image]

However, once I try to submit a sitemap in Google Search Console, I am getting this error:

[image]

The sitemap is valid, and it's hosted in the second verified domain that I also have in my Google Search Console.

Is this a bug or something needs to be done differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug.

I.e. you are a validated owner of GSC properties of siteA.com and siteB.com.

If you are logged in into your GSC property of siteA.com, you can add only sitemap hosted under siteA.com, like siteA.com/sitemap.xml.

And, vice versa, if you are logged in into your GSC property of siteB.com, you can add only sitemap hosted under siteB.com, like siteB.com/sitemap.xml.

As stated in the notice text you see in your screenshot, both sitemaps may contain URLs from both sites: siteA.com/sitemap.xml may content URLs from siteB.com, and vice versa. The requirement for this: verified ownership of GSC properties of both sites.

In fact I never pulled urls from multiple domains into the same sitemap. Nevertheless I guess the analytics data will be visible only in the corresponding GSC property. At least because whole filters are domain-relative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got it now. However, I have one more question. If I submit `siteA.com/sitemap.xml` that contains the links of both sites, I would not see analytics for `siteB` inside the `siteA` property, right? That is what I originally wanted.

Comment: I updated my answer